# R: Setting limits to scale_x_yearqtr in ggplot for yearqtr (zoo)

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, zoo, as.date

I'm working with the data set resembling the extract below:

```
head(nomis.lng.agg)
  quarter decile           avg.val
1 2004 Q4                1 5.680000
2 2005 Q1                1 5.745763
3 2005 Q2                1 5.503341
4 2005 Q3                1 5.668224
5 2005 Q4                1 5.244604
6 2006 Q1                1 5.347222
```

The variable *quarter* is of class `yearqtr` as generated by `zoo`. The remaining two columns are numerical. I'm currently generating a plot that uses the following `ggplot` syntax:

```
ggplot(data = subset(x = df,
                     subset = df$decile== 1 |
                         df$decile== 10),
       aes(x = quarter, y = avg.val, group = decile)) +
    geom_line(aes(linetype=as.factor(decile)),
              size = 1) +
    scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", n  = 5) +
    xlab("Quarter") +
    ylab("Average val") +
    ggtitle("Plot") +
    scale_linetype_discrete(name="Legend") +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black"),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "gray"),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
          legend.key.width=unit(1.5,"cm"),
          legend.position = "bottom",
          legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
          legend.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
          plot.title = element_text(face="bold"),
          plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black"))
```

The plot is almost perfect with exception of the x-axis. The current x-axis looks like that:
[image: broken axis]

My focus is on the code `scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", n  = 5)`. As my data starts from **2004 Q4** I'm not interested in plotting **2004 Q1**, but I want to set the limits with:

```
scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", 
                    limits=c(min(quarter), max=max(quarter)))
```

However, this doesn't yield the desired results, despite:

```
min(df$quarter)
[1] "2004 Q4"
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you just didn't specify the `limits` properly. In addition, to achieve greater control over the appearance, use the `breaks` argument (rather than `n`).

```
# some data
df <- data.frame(x = as.yearqtr(2004 + seq(3, 8)/4), y = sample(1:6)) 

# setting limits only
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_yearqtr(limits = c(min(df$x), max(df$x)),
                  format = "%YQ%q")
```

[image]

```
# setting breaks
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = seq(from = min(df$x), to = max(df$x), by = 0.25),
                  format = "%YQ%q")
```

[image]