# Strange behaviour of GGPLOT when x-axis corresponds Date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below `GGPLOT` :

```
library(zoo)
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
Data = data.frame('class' = c(rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 8), c('a', 'b')), 'Date' = as.yearqtr(rep(c('2021 Q4', '2022 Q1', '2022 Q2', '2022 Q3', '2022 Q4', '2023 Q1', '2023 Q2', '2023 Q3', '2023 Q4' ), each = 3))[-27], 'Value' = 1:26)
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = class)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', width = 0.1)
```

With this I am getting below plot :

[image]

As you see the first date is flowing out of the plot window.

Any pointer why is it happening and how to correct this will be very helpful.

Also, how can I get `x-axis` tick for all dates instead of having alternate dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from using `as.yearqtr` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679055/r-setting-limits-to-scale-x-yearqtr-in-ggplot-for-yearqtr-zoo)

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = class)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', width = 0.1) +
  scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = seq(from = min(Data$Date), to = max(Data$Date), by = 0.25), format = "%YQ%q")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you make Date a factor with `factor(Date)` you'll solve both of your problems.
You'll notice you get really skinny bars. Just change your `width` argument inside `geom_bar()` to `0.5`.

`ggplot(Data, aes(x = factor(Date), y = Value, fill = class)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', width = 0.5)`

[Link to output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofKRw.png)

Comment: Thanks. But I would try to avoid changing date to factor because if I have lot many dates then the plot will look messy

Comment: Good point, thanks for the comment